# .EPS file rotation via ImageMagick or GhostScript command line

Tags: php, rotation, imagemagick, ghostscript

I want to rotate `.eps` file using imagemagick or GhostScript command line. I have successfully rotated `.tif/.tiff` file but unable to rotate `.eps` file.

**What I have tried?**

> **Using ImagicMagick**

I have tried following commands.

```
/usr/bin/convert /usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps -rotate 90 /usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps
```

Result : -

Whole eps file become black and there is no content in file. File size also increased to 3.3MB from 1.3MB

> **Using GhostScript**

I have tried following commands.

```
gs -c '612 0 translate 90 rotate' -f /usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps
gs -dEPSCrop -c "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice" -f input.eps -c quit
gs -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=/usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps -c "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice" -f /usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps -c quit
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=/usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice" -f /usr/local/1476864737b31068.eps
```

Result : -

No command do rotation and with last command, whole eps file become white but there is noting in file. File size also reduced to 166KB from 1.3MB

**[Sample .EPS FILE](http://surl.review/1476864737b31068.eps)**

**Note**: I am trying to rotate source (.eps) file, I don't need rotation on output file like JPG, PNG etc file.

Comment: Its probably not going to be possible to help you without seeing an example EPS program, and knowing the version of Ghostscript you are using. The simple way to deal with this is to use the BoundingBox of the EPS to set the media, rotated by the requisite amount, and then add rotate and translate operations to do the actual manipulation. Output to the eps2write device to get a new EPS program. EPS is actually intended to be inserted into an enclosing PostScirpt program so this should be trivial to achieve.

Comment: @KenS can you tell me how can I see which version is installed of gs?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I mean the Ghostscript version. Type gs --help, or look at the backchannel for any of the Ghostscript command lines you posted, gs always declares its version on stdout.

Comment: @KenS Its Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05) I also added sample file link in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you didn't say which way you wanted the file rotated, nor by how much.

This command line:

```
gs -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=out.eps -c "<</PageSize [569 944]>>setpagedevice 569 0 translate 90 rotate" -f 1476864737b31068.eps
```

Creates a new EPS file which is rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise with respect to the original. Obviously you'll need to alter the translate and rotate operands if you want to rotate by different amounts.

Of course, EPS files are meant to be included in an enclosing PostScript program so the scaling and rotation are normally performed there.

Final note; this isn't simply 'rotating the EPS', the code between -c and -f does that. What this does is interpret the EPS to graphics primitives, pass those primitives to the device, and then assemble a new output file containing an appropriate representation of those primitives.

So the resulting EPS file's contents look **nothing** like the contents of the original EPS file.

By the way, you might want to consider a different file sharing service. That one tried to download a browser extension (video download helper) before letting me download the file, and when I refused redirected me to another (advertising) site which tried to install malware....

Comment: I have update file host, now please try to download this file.

Comment: With your command, result is still same, Should I need to install any additional module or something?

Comment: One more thing, I am executing this command via PHP, but when I run your command in terminal, it ask to me to press ENTER to continue.

Comment: I did already download the file, I was just astonished at being exposed to what my virus scanner claimed was malware. Your file, using the command I posted, works fine for me. Possibly there is something odd about your Ubuntu setup, packagers have been known to make changes to Ghostscript. How are you verifying that the 'result is the same' ? As regards not being prompted for a key press, can I suggest you read the documentation ?

Comment: Thank you sir, I just added `-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE ` in command to make it press "return" free. Your command works for me now, I think there must be some path issue before when I tried you command.

Comment: The issue happens when ever I overwrite source file. If output file is different then it rotation works.

Comment: You can't overwrite the source with the destination (and really you should not want to). As soon as you start GS it opens the output file for writing, if that's the same as the input file then its truncated to nothing, and hence you will get empty output.

Comment: That same thing was happening. Now I am stacked with rotation angle. I want to develop option to rotate right/left and on right I assign 90 to rotation command and -90 on left but the Result is not OK. Can you recommend me something on this?

Comment: Not with that amount of information. To be frank, if you want to meddle with PostScript you are going to have to learn some of the basics of the language.

Comment: can you tell me how can I update GhostScript via terminal ?

Comment: Clone the Git repository using git clone git://git.ghostscript.com/ghostpdl.git then change into the source directory top level, do ./configure and then make (possibly make install if you want it installed too)